# Django ValueError The given username must be set from form self on form overridden save method

Tags: django, django-forms

I´m in a django simple 3.2.9 project. When i try to override my form save method, y get next error:

> ValueError  The given username must be set from form self

It´s quite annoying, cause if I don´t override and call the save functionality from the view, it works just fine, but if I override method, it seems it can´t get self attributes from form, though it can do that on other validation methods within the class.

This, my RegisterForm class.

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username=forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        min_length=4,max_length=50,
        widget=TextInput(attrs={
            'class':'form-control'
        })
    )
    email=forms.EmailField(
        required=True,
        min_length=4,max_length=50,
        widget=TextInput(attrs={
            'class':'form-control'
        })
    )
    pwd=forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        min_length=4,max_length=50,
        widget=PasswordInput(attrs={
            'class':'form-control'
        })
    )
    pwdr=forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        min_length=4,max_length=50,
        widget=PasswordInput(attrs={
            'class':'form-control'
        })
    )

    def clean_username(self):
        username=self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Ese nombre de usuario ya se encuentra en uso')
        return username

    def clean_email(self):
        email=self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Ese email ya se encuentra en uso')
        return email

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data=super().clean()

        if cleaned_data.get('pwd')!= cleaned_data.get('pwdr'):
            self.add_error('pwdr','Las contraseñas no coinciden')
            return redirect('register')

        return redirect('home')

    def save(self):
        username=self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email=self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        pwd=self.cleaned_data.get('pwd')
        
        return User.objects.create_user(
            username,
            email,
            pwd
        )
```

This self contents from print(self) inside save method

> label for="id_username">Username:<input
>
> > type="text" name="username" value="vidalon" class="form-control"
> > maxlength="50" minlength="4" required id="id_username">
> >
> > Email: Pwd: Pwdr:
>
> ---UPDATED---
> I got this from [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_data)
>
> where we can read the following:
>
> Note that Form.add_error() automatically removes the relevant field
> from cleaned_data.

So basically i had a validation on two password fields and a form class with a clean method to validate these two related fields like this:

```
def clean(self):
        cleaned_data=super().clean()

        if cleaned_data.get('pwd')!= cleaned_data.get('pwdr'):
            self.add_error('pwdr','Passwords doesn´t match')
            return redirect('register')

        return redirect('home')
```

So i guess question is solved, now it makes sense keep coding!
Thanks for the interest

Comment: `clean` is supposed to return a dictionary, not a HTTP redirect to another page.

Comment: Not clean, but self itself printed above. print(self.cleaned_data) returns empty dictionary in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this from [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_data)

where we can read the following:

Note that Form.add_error() automatically removes the relevant field from cleaned_data.